# Android Layout content display issue

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to display two texts in a layout such that they are displayed one after the other but the following code is pasting the strings right above each other. What should I do. I tried to exchange fill_parent & wrap_content between the two textviews but it is worthless

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".StartingPoint" />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
    android:text="@string/testing"
    tools:context=".StartingPoint" />
```

Comment: you need to display both text horizontally??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the property **below** in the second TextView and set on the **below** property the **id** of the first TextView

change your two TextView by this two:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
android:layout_centerVertical="false"
android:text="@string/hello_world"
tools:context=".StartingPoint" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
android:layout_centerVertical="false"
android:text="@string/testing"
tools:context=".StartingPoint" />
```

But you need to read the documentation at android developers first, because that is very basic.

Hope to help :)

Comment: how can I put the property. I am beginner so I don't know anything about XML

Comment: @AlfredJames, Maybe you should learn a bit before starting the development?

Comment: like @Egor says you should learn a bit by learning on android developers, I edit my answer to help this time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinearLayout` as the parent layout and set its `orientation` to `horizontal`. This will work.

Comment: thanks. It has worked partially but where do I find the orientation

Comment: @AlfredJames, Hope you've found the answer already and strongly recommend you to buy yourself a good Android book for beginners and study it carefully before you begin developing real-world applications. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the RelativeLayout how it has to place the different views.

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

It could be simpler to use a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you need RelativeLayout menas,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="FirstText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="secondText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Else you need LinearLayout means,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FirstText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="secondText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the Case of Relative layout you need the textview is one by one means use this parameter,  `android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"` else you are using LinearLayout means use this parameter `android:orientation="vertical"`